# Date specification in dataframe

Tags: r, function, date

I have a dataset with 3 months worth of observations. Each column corresponds to a specific date and each row corresponds to a specific area. The last column of the dataset is the "week sum" (sums up the values for the area over the last 7 days). Here is a sample of the dataset:

```
 2020-09-15 2020-09-16 2020-09-17 2020-09-18 2020-09-19 2020-09-20 2020-09-21 2020-09-22 2020-09-23 2020-09-24 week_sum
       1463       1619       1624       1664       1673       1690       1691       1714       1715       1738    11885
       4812       5003       5021       5033       5047       5061       5087       5124       5141       5165    35658
        629        809        809        824        830        835        838        848        851        857     5883
```

I am trying to create a function in R that allows users to specify either a specific date range such as 2020-09-16: 2020-09-22 OR a function that allows users to specify which week or month to select data from, but I am not quite sure how to do this in R. Could somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this built-in function. You have to set a dataframe and the min and max dates. Here the code:

```
#Function
myfun <- function(x,mindate,maxdate)
{
  #Filter names
  v1 <- as.Date(names(x))
  #Set filter
  v2 <- which(v1>=as.Date(mindate) & v1<=as.Date(maxdate))
  #Create filtered data
  y <- x[,v2]
  #Compute sum
  y$Sum <- rowSums(y)
  return(y)
}
#Apply
myfun(x = df,mindate = "2020-09-16",maxdate = "2020-09-22")
```

Output:

```
  2020-09-16 2020-09-17 2020-09-18 2020-09-19 2020-09-20 2020-09-21 2020-09-22   Sum
1       1619       1624       1664       1673       1690       1691       1714 11675
2       5003       5021       5033       5047       5061       5087       5124 35376
3        809        809        824        830        835        838        848  5793
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(`2020-09-15` = c(1463L, 4812L, 629L), `2020-09-16` = c(1619L, 
5003L, 809L), `2020-09-17` = c(1624L, 5021L, 809L), `2020-09-18` = c(1664L, 
5033L, 824L), `2020-09-19` = c(1673L, 5047L, 830L), `2020-09-20` = c(1690L, 
5061L, 835L), `2020-09-21` = c(1691L, 5087L, 838L), `2020-09-22` = c(1714L, 
5124L, 848L), `2020-09-23` = c(1715L, 5141L, 851L), `2020-09-24` = c(1738L, 
5165L, 857L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```